# How to Publish List of Objects usingRabbitMq MassTransit version 8.0.3 .Net 6

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, .net-6.0, masstransit

I have an API that works fine when calling the IBusControl Publish method and sending one object of a model Employee, but as soon as I change my Publisher to publish a list then it swallows it and returns no error in the Catch(Exception) part. The queue already exist and is created by the consumer, my problem is that I cannot publish a message successfully, so I'm reaching out to see if anyone has send a collection of objects to a queue successfully? Please see my code below:

When trying to publish a list:

```
try
  {
    var Employees= await _empRepository.GetPhase1Customers(); //List of EmployeeEvent model
    //batch of 5
    int batchSize = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < Employees.Count; i += batchSize)
    {
      var batchEmployees = Employees.Skip(i).Take(batchSize).ToList();

      var response = new { Employees = batchEmployees };
      var createEmployeeEventMsg = Impromptu.ActLike<IEmployeeEvent>(response);
      await _bus.Publish<IEmployeeEvent>((object)createEmployeeEventMsg);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    _loggerService.LogInformation("Could not Publish Employees", ex.Message);
  }
}
```

IEmployeeEvent

```
  public interface IEmployeeEvent
  {
    List<EmployeeEvent> Employees { get; set; }
  }
```

EmployeeEvent

```
public class EmployeeEvent
  {
    public int EmployeeId{ get; set; }
    public int CellNo { get; set; }
    public stringAddress { get; set; }
  }
```

I have tried passing one Employee object and the code works fine, but when I publish a list no error appears in the exception, the error is swallowed and the console App just shuts down.